# Automatically replicate table data into another table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a way to automatically replicate the table into another table where in if table A has changes, then it will also change the data in the 2nd table.

Comment: Would a View do what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You  can use triggers or replication,but replication will be a overkill for a single table..See below example for more details

Changes in Table A,should replicate to table B

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[a](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [char](2) NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[b](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [char](2) NULL
)
```

Now create trigger which replicates only data changes

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[trg_test]
on [dbo].[a]
for insert,update,delete
as 

begin

set nocount on


--updated
if exists(select 1 from inserted) and exists(select 1 from deleted)
begin

update b
set b.id=i.id,
    b.name=i.name
    from b
    join
    inserted i
    on b.id<>i.id and b.name<>i.name
    join deleted d
    on b.id=d.id and b.name=d.name
return

end

--inserted 
if exists(select 1 from inserted)
begin

insert into b
select * from inserted
end



--deleted
if exists(select 1 from deleted)
begin

delete b
from
deleted d
join
b
on b.id=d.id


end

end
```

now do some random datachanges

```
--inserts

    insert into a
    select 1,'d'
    union all
    select 3,'c'


--updates
update 
a
set id=4

--deletes
delete from a
```

you can check at each stage to see data replication to b